# React like text input

Tags: angularjs

I'm experimenting with angular architecture, and I'm trying to get an input field to behave like in a react / redux app.

I would like to have a text input field with a directive on it that by passes the normal 2 way binding behavior.

This is what I have so far:

```
<input type="text" input-update="address1" ng-value="state.value" />
```

the directive

```
export default function ($rootScope) {
  return {
    resrtict: 'A',
    scope: {
      inputUpdate: '@',
    },
    replace: false,
    link: (scope, element) => {
      element.bind('keypress', event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const message = {
          address: scope.inputUpdate,
          payload: event.key,
        };
        $rootScope.$emit('updateMailbox', message);
        return false;
      });
    },
  };
}
```

then in the controller I listen for the $emit and update the scope.
However, this just adds on chars to the end of the string. If someone wanted to edit the value and add a char in the middle of the string, it wouldn't work. Also, backspace isn't being handled.

I think what I need is a way to get the out come of the input change but prevent it from rendering.

Does anyone have any experience doing something like this?
I don't really care if this is not the "angular" way.

Comment: Try `keyup` for backspace

Comment: How would I get the cursor position to know which char to delete in the string?

Comment: btw, as I can see, you're triggering `bind` and trying to get var from `scope`. `scope` doesn't know a thing about bind. You should use element.val() at least, I suppose.

Comment: Sorry, your question about cursor position make me feel, that I don't understand what you up to.

Comment: ng-value not suitable here as well...

Comment: The scope isn't used to get the val, it's used to get the address to route the update to.